# PHP - html image link displayed as text

Tags: php, html, image, output, buddypress

I am new in this so I'll try to be clear as I can.

I want to display\output, using php, page an image link html tag if user filed not empty like this on client side:

```
<a href="[dynamic from user filed]" title="My facebook">
<img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a>
```

so I wrote this but it always displays on html (client) the filed data as text without the all the html code (no html on client):

```
<div>
 <?php 
   $Usr_Url = bp_member_profile_data('field=facebook' );
   if ( !empty( $Usr_Url )) {   ?>

    <a href="<?php $Usr_Url; ?>" title="My facebook">
    <img src="images/facebook.png"   alt="facebook" /></a>

  <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

I suppose it is security issue so I need to make the code a server side code or something, can you give an advice please?

the current output seems to be always the user filed on html:  www.facebook.com/try

*(need to add the I am retrieving buddypress field bp_member_profile_data(filed='filedname') and that sections works)

Comment: You need to clarify your question more, What exactly do you want?

Comment: instead of closing your php en reopening it you can place the <a></a> between this: echo '<a> .... </a>'; NOTE: !empty means IS NOT empty.

Comment: *`I want to display an image link if empty`* but you only display the image if it **isn't** empty -> `if( !empty($Usr_Url)) {`

Comment: It would help if you showed the HTML this was producing and checked the return value from the function call - I suspect that the answer lies outwith the snippet you've shown us.

Comment: Please provide the HTML.

Comment: thank you for your commenting, I have made it a little clearer. and I also tried writing using the echo but it was the same outcome.

Comment: I gotta say this is the coolest forum ever! tried all the suggestions but still same output. php is ignoring my html and print only the filed data.

Comment: I can say all the suggestions works great without the if but when inserting the if in any case the image link create a case which all html is ignored. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it the wrong way. Do it like this:

```
   <?php 
       $Usr_Url = bp_member_profile_data('field=facebook' );
       if ( !empty( $Usr_Url )) 
       {       
       echo "<a href=".$Usr_Url."title='My facebook' <img src='images/facebook.png'   alt='facebook' /></a>";
       }
     ?>
```

Comment if there are errors.

Comment: or simply `<a href="<?php echo $Usr_Url; ?>" title="My facebook">`
as pre @user3773984's code in question.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. did you intend to leave the <a> tag opene?

Comment: tried the first suggestion but still it gave same output. ignored my html code.

Comment: please mention the person using "@" @user3773984

Comment: @stacky BTW, only you are displayed on the @ list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. It displays the image when Usr_Url is NOT empty:

```
<?php 
  $Usr_Url = bp_member_profile_data('field=facebook' );
  if ( $Usr_Url != "" ) { 
  echo '<a href="'. $Usr_Url .'" title="My facebook"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="facebook" /></a>'; } else { echo '$Usr_Url is empty...'; }
?>
```

I hope it helps :)

Comment: sorry, fixed my text. i'll try it.

Comment: I noticed that on chrome it is displayed: very long field with a quat on both sides: 
<div>"          www.facebook.com/try           "</div>

Comment: @user3773984 I just updated the code :) It now displays the image when Usr_Url is not empty. Please go ahead and try it for yourself :)

Comment: Sorry but not working. I am so frustrated. I tried everything. seems like when adding the if the problems starts. when I takes it out all works.

Comment: @user3773984 I just updated the code again. It now detects the "emptyness" of Usr_Url in another way. Please go ahead and try it :)

Comment: I did that but same result, with the if all html ignored and without all great. could it be wordpress security or something?

Comment: yeah it might just be wordpress, cuz i know that my code works ;)

Answer (score 0):

If wanting to output text from inside a PHP code block you need to use echo:

```
<?php
$Usr_Url = 'http://example.com';
echo '<a href="'.$Usr_Url.'">Example URL</a>';
...    
?>
```

Or alternatively, you can mix in PHP code blocks into your HTML:

```
<?php $Usr_Url = 'http://example.com'; ?>
<a href="<? echo $Usr_Url?>">Example URL</a>
...
```

You can't just stick HTML elements into your PHP code blocks though, as this breaks the syntax as in the original post.

To rework your code:

```
<div>
 <?php 
   $Usr_Url = bp_member_profile_data('field=facebook' );
   if ( !empty( $Usr_Url )) { 

    echo '<a href="'.$Usr_Url.'" title="My facebook">';
    echo '<img src="images/facebook.png"   alt="facebook" /></a>';

  } ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: second option this is ok but if user data is empty it will display empty field.

Comment: tried the first suggestion but still it gave same output. ignored my html code.

Comment: Have reworked your code in my original answer - that should really work. Otherwise, I suspect that nothing is coming back from the bp_member_profile_data call

Comment: Malcolm, I can say all the suggestions works great without the if but when inserting the if in any case the image link create a case which all html is ignored. any suggestions?